# "Two tier" theoretical epistemic modality

Tags: germanic-languages, auxiliary-verbs, evidentiality, modality

Quite recently I have noticed that most Bavarian verbs can become theoretical epistemic modal. What I mean by that is that you can take any verb, e.g. "[i] ko" - "[I] can", and turn it into it's theoretical form "[i] kand" - "[I] could". The special thing about Bavarian though is that you can make it even more theoretical and turn it into "[i] kandad" which could be translated to "[I] could (in theory)". Another example is "[i] muas" - "[I] must/need to" turning to "[i] miassd" - "[I] would need to" and finally "[i] miassad" - "[I] would need to (in theory)".

**Are there other languages that have this "two tier system"?** I'm especially interested in other Germanic languages.

I am sorry if I misused any technical term. I just got into studying them, so if they are misused, please tell so I can fix it.

Comment: Concerning misuse of technical terms: Insisting on Bavarian being a Germanic *language* in every second post becomes a little annyoing after a while ;)

Comment: Do you have evidence that speaks against it? If so, please show me, UNESCO (who declared Bavarian as endangered **language**) and while you are at it, change the English Wikipedia article, which also talks about it as language. At most you can argue that it is a group of dialects, but it is definitely NOT a dialect of standard German.

Comment: Yes. I rely on the, as far as I got to know it in my linguistics course of studies, most widely accepted definition that speakers of different dialects can understand each other, while speakers of different languages cannot (although those definitions are of course always highly vague, especially when there are dialect continuums). Clearly, speakers of High German or other German dialects can understand Bavarian speakers and vice versa. If it were a different language, mutual communication between Standard German and Bavarian would have to be about as difficult as mutual communication...

Comment: ... between Standard German and, e.g. Dutch, which could as well be seen as a German dialect but is rather classified as a language due to the distinction I mentioned above.

Comment: A more precise classification according to Heinz Kloss, to find [here](http://ids-pub.bsz-bw.de/files/1351/Kloss_Die_Entwicklung_neuer_germanischer_Kultursprachen_seit_1800_1978.pdf) (which also explicitly classifies Bavarian as a dialect of German by the way, p. 81), involves the notions of "Dachsprache", "Ausbausprache" and "Abstandsprache", all of which a language needs to fulfill in order to be classified as an independent language rather than a dialect. I don't want to go into the details about it here, but you can read up on it in the original source I linked...

Comment: ... as well as on the [German Wikipedia article on dialects](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialekt), if you put your trust into Wikipedia (I consider Wikiepdia an excellent collection of knolwedge and believe that the community has high standards on quality, I use it myself everday, but as well-researched as an article be, it is not the gold standard to questionlessly rely on and in any case not a scientific source to cite from).

Comment: I don't usually participate in writing Wikipedia articles, but if you are enthusiastic enough, why not convincing the community to change [the German article on Bavarian](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bairische_Dialekte), containing the word "Dialekt" not only in the title and introductory sentence but another 90 times in the article. I'm being serious - if you can provide reliable evidence that the classification as a language is linguistically wrong, they sure will appreciate your improvement of the article's quality.

Comment: Yes, those definitions are disputable and there might be people arguing against Bavarian being merely a dialect. But if so, I'd like YOU to provide some evidence which scientifically accepted theories would agree on this claim, then I am ready to re-think my argument. But one mention by UNESCO and an English Wikipedia article are not scientific evidence.

Comment: * second to last comment: "that the clsasification as a *dialect* is linguistically wrong"

Comment: OK, so there are many points which I disagree on. StackExchange comments is not made for such discussions though and the topic is not relevant for this question anyway. If you want, we can continue this conversation on my IRC channel #boarbar. If you don't have an IRC client you can just go here: https://kiwiirc.com/client

Comment: I actually didn't feel like starting a whole discussion, just replied to your demand for evidence which then got a little longer. I appreciate that you are enthusiastic enough about it to defend your point in some deeper discussion, but I'm not that interested in it ;)

Comment: Thanks for the invitation though. My refusal was not meant as an offense, I really just lost interest for this kind of discussion after I used to participate in such conversations a lot ;)

Comment: Ah, so you get to make your points and I don't? Your Heiz Kloss calls "Bayrisch" a dialect, which isn't a dialect nor a language but the adjective for the state of Bavaria. In all of these article related to that, Bavarian is called either a "language" or "dialect group". When it is called "dialect" then one can argue that AE and BE are also often called "dialect" of English. I doubt you ever heard real Bavarian, otherwise you wouldn't say that you can understand it. Since every Bavarian learns German at school it's also hard to tell if Bavarians would understand German without studying it.

Comment: I didn't mean to keep you from making your points, but simply, just as I said, am not interested in extending the discussion. I will stop commenting now, otherwise the comment section gets too long here.

Comment: I have no problem in calling Bavarian a "language", but I have difficulties in understanding what "theoretical epistemic modality" should mean applied to modal verbs. Trying to use the terminology of logic for linguistic phenomena is futile (at least) because linguistic phenomena live in another category. Having said this, you can find some interesting information on Germanic modal verbs here: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%A4teritopr%C3%A4sens